# Surely does WKProcessPool make multiple webviews share 'httpOnly' cookies immediately? (iOS9/10)

Tags: ios, cookies, webview

I confirm that shared WKProcessPool make webviews share cookies immediately only in case of they are NOT `httpOnly`.

But, I can't see cookies of `httpOnly`.

And I think they are NOT shared in multiple webviews **immediately**.

Do you have any experience about it?

Answer (score 0):

WKProcess Pool surely share all cookies among multiple webviews even it is `httpOnly`.

I made new iOS project for experiment of WKProcessPool, and try test many time.

I will upload the project soon.